# Google Script loses precision when using a time value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using a script that creates calendar events using information typed on a spreadsheet, where I have a starting and ending time in two cells. However, when I try to get the start / end times for events, the values get a **2'20"** difference (the value I get is

```
Sat Dec 30 1899 18:57:40 GMT-0430 (VEST)
```

but the cell value is **19:00:00**).

- Is there a way of fixing this 2'20" offset? Is that a bug? The difference I see is the "VEST" time instead of "VET" (Venezuela Standard Time) value.
- In case it's a bug, is it always the same time difference (2'20")? I that case, I can fix that offset by adding those seconds to that date.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not where you seem to think it is...

there is no 'hours' values in javascript nor 'date' values, a date object is always a complete date in day, month, year, hours, minutes, seconds ans milliseconds, no matter how you choose to visualize it.

The value you show comes from the logger that shows always the complete date object and since you value does not define a valid date it considers that it's 0, ie the reference day of the spreadsheet. To check that just type 0 in a spreadsheet cell and force the number format to be a date, you'll get `30/12/1899 00:00:00`

That gives you a part of an answer as it explains why... now to answer your question and to provide an answer there are a few possible way to get through this.

The easiest one is to combine your 2 cells in one at spreadsheet level by creating a 3rd cell in which you use a simple formula :

considering you have date in `A1` and hour in `B1`, create C1 with formula `=A1+B1`

That was easy but you might not be willing to have an extra cell... You could eventually use a hidden cell that does the (simple) addition and have your script read that cell instead of the 2 other ones...

The other possibility is to make this addition in the script itself, here is a script with a step by step process to be as clear as possible.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var day = new Date(sh.getRange('A1').getValue());
  var time = new Date(sh.getRange('B1').getValue());
  var hour = time.getHours();
  var min = time.getMinutes();
Logger.log(day+'  + '+time+'  '+hour+':'+min+'   =  '+ new Date(day.setHours(hour,min,0,0)));
}
```

result in the logger : (in Belgian time)

```
[13-06-21 17:16:19:071 CEST] Fri Dec 27 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)  + Sat Dec 30 1899 20:30:00 GMT+0100 (CET)  20:30   =  Fri Dec 27 2013 20:30:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```